# openURL:options:completionHandler: some questions

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to use the `openURL:options:completionHandler:` function to open third-party apps (such as qqmusic, netease, Tmall, etc.). When my app is in foreground, it works but when my app goes to background this function does not work. Anyone have a solutions?

This is my code:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"qqmusic://"]]){
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"qqmusic://"];
    if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {}];
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to work when your app isn't being used by the user? Where is this code that you posted?

Comment: Only the current foreground app can open URLs.  To allow background apps to do so would have a negative user experience; the user would suddenly find themselves in another app.

Comment: This is the case. Our app is based on Bluetooth technology and is connected to a Bluetooth device. The Bluetooth device has a voice function. The user can talk to the device. For example, say 'open music' , after the device is recognized, a code is sent to App, such as 'music:open', then app will call openURL this method to open the user-set music app. Do you copy?

Comment: @Paulw11 is right. Unfortunately you won't be able to implemente your desired functionality this way. This is Apples restriction. You could create a UserNotification in your callback which the user would have to tap but that's also a pretty horrible userexperience.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance that you accept an answer that just tells you that what you want to do is not possible? Because it is not possible. It's a deliberate design decision of Apple to forbid such things.

`openURL` only works when your app is in foreground. You cannot call that method while it is in background. And there are also no other APIs which would have a similar effect.

I'm using an iPhone for years, and I have seen no other app opening URLs while in the background. As an iPhone user I'm quite happy that this does not work. It would be really bad if I were just reading emails, and suddenly the Music app appears because some background app opened it up. And I would have no way to figure out which app did this. This does not happen because such a thing is not possible.